# Magento set template variable programmatically

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need to be able to send transactional emails that include a conditional sentence. I want to include a sentence in the order confirmation emails for any orders that contain certain products. There plenty of examples of how to use conditionals within a transaction emails based on the built in variables, but I want to base the conditional on my own variable that I'll create programmatically from within my own extension.

The mailer class Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Mailer does have a public setTemplateParams method, but as that method just calls the base classes setData method, even if I could access that method to set my own parameters it would overwrite the core template parameters that are necessary to show the contents of the basket.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a new order attribute where you save your conditional sentence.
Then you can access your attribute easily in the transactional email template via `{{htmlescape var=$order.getYourAttribute()}}`

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure about the getYourAttribute() bit. There could be several items in the basket, how do I determine if the basket contains any of the items I'm interested in? If the basket just contains normal products then I want to send the default order email, but if the basket contains one or more of a certain type of item then I want to include a sentence once in the email, no mater how many of that type of item are present in the basket.

Answer (score 0):

The attribute you are creating is related to which entity product or customers

For customer you can get it by 
{{var order.getCustomer().getAttrName()}}

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm sorry I don't understand how this will help me. How can I use this code to detect if a particular type of product is in the basket at checkout?